# Workaround for VM's with no Image Reference

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am looking for a workaround to deal with VM's I have migrated over that do not have image references (We have migrated several virtual machines from a on-prem VMware environment to our Azure subscription.).

I wanted to use policies such as Log Analytics agent deployment & Enable Azure backup enrollment on Windows VMs, however, these policies check for a image reference on the VM.

Is there another way maybe using tags or something else to identify the VM for polices that require an image reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be late, but this can be added to the typical condition with all the valid image references. I add the osType to ensure that Linux extensions are not deployed in Windows VMs, or viceversa:

```json
{
    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
    "equals": "Windows"
},
{
    "anyOf":[
        {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                    "equals": ""
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "equals": ""
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                    "equals": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                    "exists": "false"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "exists": "false"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                    "exists": "false"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```